# xindy: Suppress 'Cross-reference-target ("entry") does not exist' error for entries without locators

Tags: indexing, xindy

## Background

First, consider the following index entry:

```
\index{entry|see{non-existent entry}}
```

When `xindy` builds the index, it will complain about the dangling cross-reference:

```
ERROR: Cross-reference-target ("non-existent entry") does not exist!
```

We can instruct `xindy` not to validate the `see` and `seealso` cross-references by adding the following to a custom `.xdy` module:

```
(define-crossref-class "see" :unverified)
(define-crossref-class "seealso" :unverified)
```

and passing the name of that module to `xindy` using the `-M` parameter.

## Problem

I like having `xindy` validate my cross-references so I don't have dangling pointers in my index. Unfortunately, it gives me false errors in the following case:

```
\index{entry!subentry}
\index{another entry|see{entry}}
```

`xindy` complains:

```
ERROR: Cross-reference-target ("entry") does not exist!
```

I assume this is because `entry` has no locators (page numbers) itself and only has subentries.

How can I get `xindy` to mark cross-references to such locatorless entries as valid?

Comment: Any developments on this question?  I see the same problem.

Comment: @John I haven't resolved this issue yet. I [posted an email](https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/mailman/message/36295246/) to the xindy-discuss list, but haven't had any response there yet, either.